# vim - "Press ENTER or type command to continue" right after loading only?

Tags: linux, bash, osx, vim

Recently my vim has developed the habit of displaying `Press ENTER or type command to continue` the first time I do certain things right after I open it.

For example, if I'm at my shell prompt and type `vim test.txt` and then I want to jump to line 54, so I press ESC and then type `:54`, it will say `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, and then when I press ENTER, it takes me to the line.

The next time I do `:54`, or anything else in this entire vim session, it won't do this again.

But if I quit, and then open vim again, it will do this exactly once.

I suspect something in my .vimrc or a plugin or something, but I don't know. I am also not sure how to debug this, short of going through the painstaking operation of randomly commenting out things in my .vimrc and randomly disabling plugins until something fixes it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your .vimrc :)

Answer (score 1):

This is either triggered by a mapping or an autocmd (that subsequently somehow inactivates itself).

You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands.

You can also list suspecting autocmds via `:verbose autocmd CursorMoved`.